# Creepy: The cat left a half eaten rabbit in the garden

Tags: cats, eating, outdoor, hunting

Creepy warning, this question is not for the light-hearted

This morning I was making breakfast while I spotted our cat eating something in the garden. A better look showed he caught a rabbit.

The cat is now very happy and satisfied, leaving me concerned about a half eaten rabbit in the garden.

Any chances that he will return and finish the meal?

What should I do? I'd prefer my partner not to see the horror scene in our garden when she gets back from work this evening.

Should I remove the half animal? how can I dispose of it?
thanks

Comment: Related Question [How deep should I bury my pet (should I rebury)?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2210)

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a duplicate. Though really I think this is off-topic because it's about the disposal of a wild animal.

Comment: The other question is different than mine, the guy had a Rabbit which he buried. I never had a rabbit, my cat hunted it and left it partially eaten in our garden. And my question was what to do with the leftovers. I now bagged the creature and tomorrow the garbage collection service will solve my problem.

Comment: We would like it if you would actually edit the question even it's now too late because it's been marked.